# Swift 3 Function Parameter (Dictionary - Array)

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift3, func

I'm using [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) for my upload form. And I have a UPLOAD button, like this:

```
<<< ButtonRow() {
    $0.title = "UPLOAD";
}.onCellSelection { cell, row in
    var formValues = self.form.values();
    formValues["userId"] = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userId");
    self.upload(parameters: formValues); // <- How do I us formValues ?
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any?]' to expected argument type 'Array'

And I have upload() function:

```
func upload(parameters: Array<Any>) { // <- formValues?
    print(parameters);
}
```

I don't know formValues is Dictionary or Array? Anyway, how do I pass this parameters to this my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `formValues` is of type `Dictionary` not `Array`. Change your upload function parameters to this:

```
func upload(parameters: [String: Any?]) {
    print(parameters);
}
```